# Android: Is there a way to use the Google map API to show location and give directions?

Tags: android

My Bos wants me to make a app showing A GOOGLE MAP OF WHERE YOU ARE, AND THE DESTINATION, WITH DIRECTIONS UNDER IT.

i looked at the api, and it seems like it just draws the map and allows you to mark locations on it.  I was thinking if I could some how get the address from the longitude ans latitude maybe I could some how use Google maps on the web to give the directions????? and ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google API for Android just allows you to mark locations, images and points, it doesn't work as a GPS although you can use Geocoder API (Also from google) to get the longitude and latitude from a place and viceversa.
If you want to know how to get from a place to another use the Google API (not specifically for Android) although you'd receive the data in xml or json.
Good luck!

Comment: Hi,I googled google api direction, brought me to googles documention, very easy, thank you for the hint